# Управление кэшем с gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

У меня есть веб-сервис на `Flask`, в котором я делаю кэширование с помощью класса объекта `SimpleCache`. Проблема возникает в случае запуска пришожения через `gunicorn`. В каждом процессе есть свой кэш, могу ли как-то объединить кэш процессов `gunicorn` ?

Comment: В документации сказано, что SimpleCache только для сервера для разработки, поэтому не надо его использовать и возьмите, например, memcached

Comment: @andreymal вы могли бы оформить свое сообщение как ответ. Тогда я отметил бы его лучшим, т.к. он мне действительно помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/caching/), `SimpleCache` предназначен только для сервера для разработки. В нём используется самый обыкновенный питоновый словарь, в котором и хранятся кэшируемые объекты. Отсюда очевидно, что за пределы процесса такой кэш не вылезает, а gunicorn создаёт несколько процессов-воркеров, и у каждого получается свой кэш-словарь. `SimpleCache` не предназначен для таких вещей. (Даже если кому-то вдруг покажется, что это не сильно страшно, всё равно не надо так: когда надо будет сделать инвалидацию кэша, сделать её одновременно во всех процессах станет очень трудно.)

Кэш следует вынести куда-то за пределы процессов gunicorn. Та же самая документация предлагает использовать `MemcachedCache`. Естественно, надо не забыть установить в системе и запустить сам `memcached` :) Все процессы будут обращаться к нему одному, и у всех них получится общий кэш.